# member variable

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, initialization-list

Can there be a member variable in a class which is not `static` but which needs to be defined
(as a static variable is defined for reserving memory)? If so, could I have an example? If not, then why are static members the only definable members?

**BJARNE said if you want to use a member as an object ,you must define it.**

But my program is showing error when i explicitly define a member variable:

```
class test{
    int i;
    int j;
  //...
};

int test::i; // error: i is not static member.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Pubby THEN WHAT DOES BJRANE ACTUALLY MEANS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, declaring `i` and `j` in the class also defines them.

See this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int a;         // Declares and defines a member variable
    static int b;  // Declare (only) a static member variable
};

int Foo::b;    // Define the static member variable
```

You can now access `a` by declaring an object of type `Foo`, like this:

```
Foo my_foo;
my_foo.a = 10;
std::cout << "a = " << my_foo.a << '\n';
```

It's a little different for `b`: Because it is `static` it the same for all instance of `Foo`:

```
Foo my_first_foo;
Foo my_second_foo;

Foo::b = 10;
std::cout << "First b = " << my_first_foo.b << '\n';
std::cout << "Second b = " << my_second_foo.b << '\n';
std::cout << "Foo::b = " << Foo::b << '\n';
```

For the above all will print that `b` is 10.

Answer (score 0):

in that case, you would use the initialization list of `test`'s constructor to define the initial values for *an instance* like so:

```
class test {
    int i;
    int j;
  //...
public:
  test() : i(-12), j(4) {}
};
```

Comment: what does this statement means -if (and only if) you use an initialized member in away that requires it to be stored as an oject in memory ,the member must be(uniquely) defined somewhere. The initializer may not be repeated.

Comment: @10001001058 it means the definition (`int test::i(0);`) of a *static* (`class test { static int i; /* ... */ };`) must exist in one place only -- typically int `test.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

That definition reserves space for *one* integer, but there'll really be a separate integer for every instance of the class that you create.  There could be a million of them, if your program creates that many instances of `test`.

Space for a non-static member is allocated at runtime each time an instance of the class is created.  It's initialized by the class's constructor.  For example, if you wanted the integer `test::i` to be initialized to the number 42 in each instance, you'd write the constructor like this:

```
test::test(): i(42) {
}
```

Then if you do

```
test foo;
test bar;
```

you get two objects, *each* of which contains an integer with the value 42.  (The values can change after that, of course.)

Comment: is it must to define a static member ??

Comment: Yes.  Static members aren't allocated or initialized by the class's constructor, since they aren't part of any instance of the class.  That's why you have to define them separately.